# Bypassing devise signin when user registered via REST call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, devise

I am  using devise with rest enabled. I have a form that requires user authentcation / registration. The authentication is implemented in fancybox light box.

I am able to register and signin using ajax calls. Sign in seems to return a session_id. How do I get the session object after registration. Or, more like is a session object created at registration?

If one is not created how would I bypass signin the first time after registration ?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no straight forward way to do this. As of now the only way I can do this is by refreshing the page.